# Check whether a String does contain different characters as the given one in Java

Tags: java, ascii, guava

I have a fix `charset` which is the following one:

**Capitals and lowercase**:

A - Z, a-z

**Numbers**:

0-9

**Special characters**:

Ñ, É, ñ, à, @, £, $, ¥, è, é, ù, ì, ò, _, !, ", #, %, &, ', (, ), *, +, ,, -, ., /, :, ;, <, =, >, ?, §, `, SPACE, CR, LF, €, [, ], {, |, }, ^, ~, \, ß,Ä,Ö,Ü,ä,ö,ü

**I tried using the library `Guava` but my String was matched to be a non ASCII only String:**

```
if(!CharMatcher.ascii().matchesAllOf(myString)){
    //String doesn't match        
}
```

**My input String was:**

```
 smsBodyBlock.setBodyContent("A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z, Ä, Ö, Ü,a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z, ä, ö, ü,0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,Ñ, É, ñ, à, @, £, $, ¥, è, é, ù, ì, ò, _, !, , #, %, &, ', (, ), *, +, ,, -, ., /, :, ;, <, =, >, ?, §, `, SPACE, CR, LF, €, [, ], {, |, }, ^, ~, , ß\"");
```

So basically the entire charset I have written above. It didn't match as `ASCII`

Is there any fast and reliable scalable way to check if there are other chars than my predifined ones?

Comment: U could simply go though every character of the String to look for a wrong character

Comment: @ILikeSahne that would be very inefficient or?

Comment: It will not get much better. Libaries are using simular solutions

Comment: You could have a boolean array of size 256 that tells, for any latin-1 compatible unicode character, whether it is an acceptable character. That will be very fast and only consumes 256 booleans of memory. And in addition to that, you also add a condition that the € symbol is accepted too.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by a boolean array taht tells ...*

Comment: It makes sense that it didn't match ASCII. ASCII isn't what you think it is. You probably don't need to know what ASCII is because you'll probably never use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe one of the most efficient ways would be a BitSet - checking if a character is present occurs in O(1) time. It is roughly as efficient as using an array, but only needs about one-eight of the space.

```
static class MyCustomMatcher {
    // bits needed = last character + 1
    private static final BitSet matcher = new BitSet('ü' + 1);

    static {
        String other = " \r\nÑÉñà@£$¥èéùìò_!\"#%&',()*+-./:;<=>?§`€[]{|}^~\ßÄÖÜäöü";
        matcher.set(c, 'A', 'Z' + 1); // upper
        matcher.set(c, 'a', 'z' + 1); // lower
        matcher.set(c, '0', '9' + 1); // digit
        for (int i = 0; i < other.length(); i++) matcher.set(other.charAt(i));
    }

    public static boolean matchesAll(String s) {
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if (!matcher.get(s.charAt(i))) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then you can write

```
if (MyCustomMatcher.matchesAll("Hello world")) { 
   // do something
}
```

I made the class static for simplicity, but you can make it more flexible and reusable by passing the characters to match in a constructor.

Comment: Looks quite fast, but I am wondering why there's an `a` in the second foor loop, typo?

Comment: Leo yould you just elaborate why you insert 'ü' +1 in the `BitSet`constructor?

Comment: + you forgot the comma too

Comment: @Alan the minimum number of bits a BitSet needs is equal to the highest value added to the bitset + 1. If you don't specify the size you want, then the BitSet will guess the size by itself, which might result in either an oversized BitSet with unused space, or an undersized BitSet which needs to be repeatedly expanded.

But since the highest character you need to store is `'ü'` in this case, you can just tell the BitSet to allocate exactly `'ü' + 1` bits.

Answer (score 5):

This is exactly why `CharMatcher` exists, and you already use it, just not to its full extend!

The only difference is that you should define your own character set.

So, let's go:

```
CharMatcher letters = CharMatcher.inRange('a', 'z')
                  .or(CharMatcher.inRange('A', 'Z'));
CharMatcher numbers = CharMatcher.inRange('0, '9');
CharMatcher specials = CharMatcher.anyOf("ÑÉñà@£$¥èéùìò_!\"#%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?§` \r\n€[]{|}^~\\ßÄÖÜäöü");

CharMatcher allMyCharacters = letters.or(numbers).or(specials);

// If you want performance, keep the line below. If not, remove it
allMyCharacters = allMyCharacters.precomputed();

if (allMyCharacters.matchesAllOf(myString)) {
  //
}
```

Make sure you keep `allMyCharacters` a stored field somewhere, like this, for instance:

```
public class MyStringMatcher {
  private static final CharMatcher myCharacters = createCharMatcher();

  private static CharMatcher createCharMatcher() {
    CharMatcher letters = CharMatcher.inRange('a', 'z')
                  .or(CharMatcher.inRange('A', 'Z'));
    CharMatcher numbers = CharMatcher.inRange('0, '9');
    CharMatcher specials = CharMatcher.anyOf("ÑÉñà@£$¥èéùìò_!\"#%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?§` \r\n€[]{|}^~\\ßÄÖÜäöü");

    return letters.or(numbers).or(specials).precomputed();
  }

  public static boolean matches(String string) {
    return myCharacters.matchesAllOf(string);
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice. This requires a library--but the OP is using that library already. And the Guava implementation is pretty much the same as the custom solution with BitSet. If I already had Guava in my project I'd do this; otherwise I'd use the BitSet implementation.